# wondering if I wrote channel url for facebook javascript sdk right. 

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, channel

I'm wondering if I've written my channel url right. In the Javascript SDK reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ ; the section on the Channel file says:

> The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on
>   which you include the SDK. In other words, the channel file domain
>   must include www if your site is served using www, and if you modify
>   document.domain on your page you must make the same document.domain
>   change in the channel.html file as well. The protocols must also
>   match. If your page is served over https, your channelUrl must also be
>   https. Remember to use the matching protocol for the script src as
>   well.

This is my Javascript SDK page: 
**note: I put the channel.html file in the same folder as my index.php file and I'm not sure if that is correct either.**

```
<body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '278374582262040', // App ID
      **channelUrl : 'localhost/controllers/index.php/channel.html', // Channel File**
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

//the rest of the sdk code
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
channelUrl : 'localhost/controllers/index.php/channel.html'
```

You have given no protocol there at all – which means, the browser will request a file from a directory called `localhost/controllers/` underneath the current directory.

You should give the address starting with `//localhost/` – this lets the browser decide, which protocol to use, based on the protocol used to retrieve the document in whose context th script is executed – meaning, you’re on the safe side no matter if your page is browsed using HTTP or HTTPS.

> *“Remember to use the matching protocol for the script src as well.”*

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

This applies to the embedding of the JS SDK as well – use `//connect.facebook.net/…`